# Elasticsearch configure heap size with AWS OpsWorks

Tags: elasticsearch, cookbook, heap-size, aws-opsworks

Is there a way to configure opsworks to set the elasticsearch heap size when it start the instances?
I am using this cookbook https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/ and the custom json doesn't seem to have any property for heap size.

I found that `allocated_memory` in `elasticsearch_configure` is the one I need to modify but not sure if it's possible to do so in the custom json or without creating my own recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I could just specify 

`elasticsearch: {
   allocated_memory: '512m'
}`

in the custom json:
https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/issues/380